# How to add Dynamic templateUrl

Tags: angularjs

I have web application where I need to load a template with different parameters like.

```
.when('/form/:ProjectID/:FormID', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/Form.ashx?fid=' + FormID,
        controller: 'FormController'
    })
```

I am not able to get the above code working. Can someone tell me how I can fix this issue? I am new to AngularJS and not an expert.

This is the full code.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.grid', 'ngSanitize', 'angularTrix', 'ui.codemirror', 'ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/Home.ashx',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })
    .when('/project/:ProjectID', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/Projects.ashx',
        controller: 'ProjectController'
    })
    .when('/form/:ProjectID/:FormID', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/Form.ashx?fid=1',
        controller: 'FormController'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

**We can use $stateParams and templateProvider to load dynamic templateurl**

```
.state('general', {
   url: '/{type}',
   //templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
   templateProvider: ['$stateParams', '$templateRequest',
      function($stateParams, $templateRequest) 
      {
        var tplName = "pages/" + $stateParams.type + ".html";
        return $templateRequest(tplName);
      }
    ],
    // general controller instead of home
    //controller: 'homeController',
    controller: 'generalController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
```

Comment: Thanks. But its not very clear. I am new to angularjs. 

    templateUrl: 'partials/Form.ashx?fid=1',

How can I replace the above line with the stateparms?

Comment: try like this
$stateProvider
    .state('form', {
      url: '/form/:ProjectID/:FormID',
     templateUrl: 'views.parentview.html',
    controller: 'FormController'
});